# Conjugations in the comparison isomorphisms between Betti cohomology and algebraic de Rham cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, proof-explanation, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

For a smooth projective variety $X$ defined over $k$ which admits a real embedding $\sigma:k \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, its Betti cohomology is defined by
\begin{equation}
H^*_{B,\sigma}(X):=H^*(X \times_{k,\sigma}\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q}) \,,
\end{equation}
where $X \times_{k,\sigma}\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C})$ is the complex valued points of $X \times_{k,\sigma}\mathbb{C}$.

Since the embedding is real, complex conjugation acts on the points of $X \times_{k,\sigma}\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C})$, which induces an involution $F_{\infty}$ on $H^*_{B,\sigma}(X)$.

The etale cohomology is defined by
\begin{equation}
H^*_{et}(X)_{\ell}:=H^*(X \times_k \bar{k},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \,.
\end{equation}
There is a standard comparison isomorphism, $I_{\ell,\bar{\sigma}}$
\begin{equation}
I_{\ell,\bar{\sigma}}:H^*_{B,\sigma}(X) \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell} \simeq H^*_{et}(X)_{\ell}
\end{equation}
which depends on the choice of an extension of $\sigma$ to $\bar{\sigma}:\bar{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

From lots of references, under this isomorphism, the involution $F_{\infty} \otimes 1$ corresponds to the automorphism $\bar{\sigma}^*(c) \in \text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ (which acts on etale cohomology) where $c$ is complex conjugation which acts on $\bar{k}$ through the embedding.

Could anyone explain the ideas in the proof of this comparison isomorphism and the correspondence of the two involutions? Or give some references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should first understand the comparison theorem in the case of smooth varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ for finite coefficients $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$. For this you should consult SGA 4, Exposé XI.

Now given a smooth variety $X$ over $\bar{k}$ (using your notations) and an embedding $\sigma : \bar{k} \to \mathbb{C}$, there is a natural isomorphism between étale cohomology of $X$ and étale cohomology of $X_{\sigma}$ (the base change of $X$ to $\mathbb{C}$ using $\sigma$).

The result you want (the fact that complex conjugations match) follows from the functoriality of the two isomorphisms explained above. Let $c$ be the complex conjugation on $\bar{k}$ induced by the usual complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$. Given a smooth variety $X$ over $k$, there is a commutative diagram
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X_{\bar{k}} @>>> X_\mathbb{C} \\
@VVV @VVV \\
X_{\bar{k}} @>>> X_\mathbb{C}
\end{CD}$$
where the vertical arrows are given by $c$.